# What's wrong with my button and the link isn't working?

Tags: javascript, html, button

It was working just fine but then...well... I don't know what I did ...

```
<form>
<span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
font-size:24px;font-weight:bold;">
   <input onclick="window.location.href='
     https://trehebe.blogspot.gr/p/online-paraggelia.html'
     target:_blank" style="background:rgb(153, 0, 255); border-radius:20px; 
     border:1px solid rgb(217, 217, 217); 
     box-shadow:rgb (153, 153, 153) 6px 6px 5px; color:#ffffff;
     cursor:pointer; font-weight:bold; padding:10px; width:100px;" 
     type="button" value="Order" />
</span>
</form>
```

Comment: Why do you think something is wrong? Please read [ask] a proper question.

Comment: `<input onclick="window.location.href='https://trehebe.blogspot.gr/p/online-paraggelia.html'" target="_blank" style="background:rgb(153, 0, 255); border-radius:20px; border:1px solid rgb(217, 217, 217); box-shadow:rgb (153, 153, 153) 6px 6px 5px; color:#ffffff; cursor:pointer; font-weight:bold; padding:10px; width:100px;" type="button" value="Order" />`
</form>`

Comment: Why are you using an `<input>` as a link? Just use a proper `<a>` tag.

Comment: as @MikeC asked why are you using `input` tag, the attribute `target` will only works with an `<a>` tag

Answer (score 2):

Just use this:

```
onclick="window.location.href='https://trehebe.blogspot.gr/p/online-paraggelia.html';" target="_blank"
```

EDIT:

As a complete code:

```
<form><span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif; font-size:24px;  font-weight:bold;"><input onclick="window.location.href='https://trehebe.blogspot.gr/p/online-paraggelia.html;'" target="_blank" style="background:rgb(153, 0, 255); border-radius:20px; border:1px solid rgb(217, 217, 217); box-shadow:rgb (153, 153, 153) 6px 6px 5px; color:#ffffff; cursor:pointer; font-weight:bold; padding:10px; width:100px;" type="button" value="Order" /></span></form>
```

ANOTHER EDIT (explanation):

The error is with the `onclick` attribute OP didn't close it properly with a double quote. So I just added a semi-colon and a double quote to end the statement.

The `target` attribute was malformed because it originally came as `target:"_blank"`. In HTML attributes use the equal sign `target="_blank"`.

To prove here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0o81s05j/).

Comment: What did you change and why? This doesn't look like complete code.

Comment: @FelixKling I just changed `onclick` and `target` attributes as they were both malformed.

Comment: You might want to explain what *exactly* was incorrect. Also, it's fine to not have a complete example, but that requires you to explain which part you fixed (and why). "Just use this" can be easily interpreted as replacing the whole code with your (incomplete) example. But if you say something like: "The value of the `href` attribute is not valid, ..." then it's a lot clearer...

Comment: @FelixKling there I've added a more detailed explanation.